# Mercurial local branching and pushing to shared repository

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I created a branch on my local Mercurial repository.  I want to push to the shared repository so my work can be backed up, but I don't want other project members to see the branch.

What's the standard operating procedure in this case?

I'd like to avoid having the repository get full of developer branches that I don't need to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're conflating two issues. If you need your branches backed up, simply clone your local repository someplace else that is actually backed up, but not visible to your coworkers (that is, not the main repository). You can always easily pull changesets from more than one repository in case that becomes necessary.

Comment: Hi, how can I pull from that local backup clone into my working copy?  Thanks.